# Diffie-Hellman set generator parameter in BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, diffie-hellman

I want to generate new DH parameter as defined in PKCS #3:

```
DHParameter ::= SEQUENCE {
    prime INTEGER, -- p
    base INTEGER, -- g
    privateValueLength INTEGER OPTIONAL
}
```

using BouncyCastle. My current code

```
DHParametersGenerator generator = new DHParametersGenerator();  
generator.init(2048, DEFAULT_PRIME_CERTAINTY, new SecureRandom());
DHParameters params = generator.generateParameters();
```

works fine, but I can't see a way to set the **base** on my own other than modifying the library. Is there some workaround I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most DH implementations uses predefined base value, so it can be no way for doing that without sources modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set the base of your choice using the same class. So your code will become:-

```
DHParametersGenerator generator = new DHParametersGenerator();  
generator.init(2048, DEFAULT_PRIME_CERTAINTY, new SecureRandom());
DHParameters params = generator.generateParameters();
DHParameters realParams = new DHParameters(params.getP(), BigInteger.valueOf(2));
```